# Swiping Through Multiple Images in FullScreen similar to Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Right now, I am trying to integrate Facebook's functionality regarding viewing multiple images when in full screen by swiping either left or right to the next or previous image.

```
// MARK: Media View
extension PostView {
    func mediaView(media: [MediaOBJ]) -> some View {
        VStack {
            if media.count > 1 {
                manyMediaView(media: media)
                    .frame(height: 200)
            } else {
                singleMediaView(media: media[0])
                    .frame(minWidth: 250)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func manyMediaView(media: [MediaOBJ]) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            TabView(selection: $selectedImageIndex) {
                ForEach(media.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    imageView(media: media[index])
                        .tag(index)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .automatic))
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                if value.translation.width > 50 {
                    selectedImageIndex = max(selectedImageIndex - 1, 0)
                } else if value.translation.width < -50 {
                    selectedImageIndex = min(selectedImageIndex + 1, media.count - 1)
                }
            }
        )
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func singleMediaView(media: MediaOBJ) -> some View {
        VStack {
            switch media.kind {
            case .photo:
                if media.isGIF {
                    gifView(url: media.link)
                        .frame(height: 200)
                } else {
                    singleImageView(media: media)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            case .video:
                VideoPlayerView(url: media.link)
                    .frame(height: 300)
            default:
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func gifView(url: URL) -> some View {
        GIFPlayerView(gifURL: url)
            .maxWidth()
            .frame(height: 200)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
    
    
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func singleImageView(media: MediaOBJ) -> some View {
        AsyncImage(url: media.link) { phase in
            switch phase {
            case .success(let image):
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .maxHeight(600)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.selectedMedia = .init(image: image)
                    }
            case .failure:
                DefaultPlaceholder()
                    .maxHeight(600)
                    .onAppear {
                        imageLoadKey = .init()
                    }
            case .empty:
                Color.clear
            }
        }
        .id(imageLoadKey)
        .frame(minHeight: 100)
        .background(Color.clear)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .sheet(item: $selectedMedia) { image in
            SwiftUIImageViewer(image: image.image)
                .onDisappear {
                    self.selectedMedia = nil
                    self.viewModel.reload()
                }
        }
    }
    
    func loadedSingleImage(image: UIImage) -> some View {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
    
    func imageView(media: MediaOBJ) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            AsyncImage(url: media.link, content: { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(
                        width: geo.size.width,
                        height: 200,
                        alignment: .center
                    )
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture  {
                        self.selectedMedia = .init(image: image)
                    }
            }, placeholder: {
                DefaultPlaceholder()
            })
            .frame(
                width: geo.size.width,
                height: 200,
                alignment: .center
            )
            .background(Color.lightestGray)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .sheet(item: $selectedMedia) { image in
                //                SwiftUIImageViewer(image: image.image)
                MultiImageViewer(images: [image.image])
                    .onDisappear {
                        self.selectedMedia = nil
                        self.viewModel.reload()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func videoView(avPlayer: AVPlayer) -> some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: avPlayer)
            .scaledToFill()
            .maxWidth()
            .frame(height: 300, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .onAppear {
                avPlayer.play()
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                if avPlayer.isPlaying {
                    avPlayer.pause()
                } else {
                    avPlayer.play()
                }
            }
    }
    
    func audioView(media: MediaOBJ) -> some View {
        UText("")
    }
}
```

As you can see, as is I can swipe left or right to view the next or previous image in `manyMediaView` in `PostView`. However, when I try to view the images in full screen via `MultiImageViewer` , which is called in `imageView()`, I can only do so one at a time instead of swiping through them.

Here is `MultiImageViewer`:

```
import UIKit

public struct MultiImageViewer: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    let images: [Image]
    
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var lastScale: CGFloat = 1
    
    @State private var offset: CGPoint = .zero
    @State private var lastTranslation: CGSize = .zero
    
    @State private var selectedImageIndex = 0
    
    public init(images: [Image]) {
        self.images = images
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            content
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                        Button {
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        } label: {
                            Image("close-circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
    var content: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            TabView(selection: $selectedImageIndex) {
                ForEach(images.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    images[index]
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                                let swipeThreshold: CGFloat = 50
                                
                                if value.translation.width > swipeThreshold && selectedImageIndex > 0 {
                                    selectedImageIndex -= 1
                                } else if value.translation.width < -swipeThreshold {
                                    selectedImageIndex = min(selectedImageIndex + 1, images.count - 1)
                                }
                            }
                        )
                        .tag(index)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
    
    private func makeMagnificationGesture(size: CGSize) -> some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                let delta = value / lastScale
                lastScale = value
                
                // To minimize jittering
                if abs(1 - delta) > 0.01 {
                    scale *= delta
                }
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                lastScale = 1
                if scale < 1 {
                    withAnimation {
                        scale = 1
                    }
                }
                adjustMaxOffset(size: size)
            }
    }
    
    private func makeDragGesture(size: CGSize) -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                let diff = CGPoint(
                    x: value.translation.width - lastTranslation.width,
                    y: value.translation.height - lastTranslation.height
                )
                offset = .init(x: offset.x + diff.x, y: offset.y + diff.y)
                lastTranslation = value.translation
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                adjustMaxOffset(size: size)
            }
    }
    
    private func adjustMaxOffset(size: CGSize) {
        let maxOffsetX = (size.width * (scale - 1)) / 2
        let maxOffsetY = (size.height * (scale - 1)) / 2
        
        var newOffsetX = offset.x
        var newOffsetY = offset.y
        
        if abs(newOffsetX) > maxOffsetX {
            newOffsetX = maxOffsetX * (abs(newOffsetX) / newOffsetX)
        }
        if abs(newOffsetY) > maxOffsetY {
            newOffsetY = maxOffsetY * (abs(newOffsetY) / newOffsetY)
        }
        
        let newOffset = CGPoint(x: newOffsetX, y: newOffsetY)
        if newOffset != offset {
            withAnimation {
                offset = newOffset
            }
        }
        self.lastTranslation = .zero
    }
}
```

What is needed so that, like Facebook, I can swipe through each image in full screen when it comes to a post with multiple images?

Comment: I have a similar demo project in my github, it is iOS 17+ compatible though: https://github.com/MatHeartGaming/coolStuff_with_SwiftUI/tree/main/Complex%20Hero%20Animation%20with%20Synch%20ScrollViews

Comment: The app I'm working on is somewhat compatible with iOS 17+. The main issue for me is having the view detect that there's more than one image to display at full screen so like being able to have the initial image show up full screen and being able to swipe to the next image instead of having to exit full screen for the initial image and then viewing the next ones individually in full screen if that makes sense.